# Select all checkboxes of an entity reference field on creating a node

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, javascript

Drupal 8.7.x

For one of my content types I have an entity reference field referencing a taxonomy vocabulary. I have a lot of terms in this vocabulary which makes it tedious to check all the checkboxes if you practically need all of them checked. I would like to integrate a single checkbox at the top of the field in the node creation form that allows you to check/uncheck all the terms at once.

I found a few modules that do this in drupal 7 but so far I had no luck finding anything related to drupal 8.

How would I go about integrating this functionality myself ?

At the moment I have a jquery function in my theme that adds a checkbox at the top of the fields like so:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  /**
   * Check all checkboxes.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.initFootnotes = {

    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $(".form-checkboxes").prepend($('<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox shield-select-all" /><label class="option shield-select-all-label"> Select / Deselect all </label>'));

      let selector = $(".shield-select-all");
      selector.on('click', function (event) {

        console.log("the checkbox is clicked");
        let $options = $('.form-type-checkbox');

        $(".form-checkboxes").closest().find($options).each(
        console.log("I'm an option"),

        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").click(),

        )
      })
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

The select all checkbox is added but the checkboxes aren't changing their state when the select all checkbox is checked. I noly get "I'm an option" once in the console.

Thanks in advance,
Geordi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up resolving this issue with the following code:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  /**
   * Check/Uncheck all checkboxes.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.selectAll = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(".form-checkboxes").prepend($('<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox shield-select-all"/><label class="option shield-select-all-label"> Select / Deselect all </label>'));
      $(".shield-select-all").on('click', function () {
        let $isChecked = (!$(this).attr('checked'));
        $(this).parent().find('.form-type-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', $isChecked);
        $(this).attr('checked', $isChecked)
      })
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The contributed module [checkboxesjs](https://www.drupal.org/project/checkboxesjs) will do this for you out of the box.